# Bind this of parent object to this of child object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in object concept of javascript. Actually its lame question but I want to understand this concept clearly.

```
var objA = {
 a : 10,
 b : 20,
 newobjB : {
  c : 100,
  funOfObjB: function(){
   console.log(this.a)
  }
 }
}
```

Here I want to get value of parent object variable by this concept.I have tried

bind()

method but it is giving me some different data in (this) variable.

Thanks for help

Comment: `.I have tried bind()` - clearly you haven't as it's not in the code you posted. If you're having a problem with a particular piece of code, it makes sense to post that piece of code, not some other piece of code

Comment: In this case, `this` has a context of `newobjB` which doesn't have `a` property defined at all. If you want `newobjB` to inherit properties of `objA` then you need to use a prototypical inheritance.

Other approaches - using `objA.a` instead `this.a`

Comment: Javascript does not have the notion of a parent object.  One object doesn't actually contain another, it just has a reference to another object.  It is unclear what you are asking or what you're trying to use `.bind()` for.  Please clarifiy your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to reference `objA` via `newobjB` like that.

`objA` simply has a reference to to an object in the form of a property called `newobjB`. There could be multiple references to `objA.newobjB` - it is not a 1 to 1 relationship. You would have to provide `objA` to your object at `newobjB` to reference back to it<sup>1</sup>, like:

```
var objA = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
};

objA.newobjB = {
    objA: objA,
    c : 100,
    funOfObjB: function(){
        console.log(this.objA.a)
    }
};
```

<sup>1</sup>Of course you could omit attaching `objA` as a property to `newobjB` here, but I am demonstrating a use case where you need a reference back via `this`.

If you want `this` to refer to `objA` in `funOfObjB` then you can use `call` or `apply`:

```
objA.newobjB.funOfObjB.call(objA);
```